# Opening mediawiki editor in popup

Tags: mediawiki

Was trying to figure out if there is a way to open a mediawiki editor in a popup window. First I thought I could use action=render, but as both starting the edit and render is an action, they don't seem to work together. Preferably I want it to work so that the editor starts with only the editor controlls but not the standard menus.

Looking at the settings, it does seem like WYSIWYG (and potentially other editors) can be opened in such a mode, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to set it up. 
Tried changing the setting in Special:Preferences page, basically ensuring both "Open rich editor in a popup" but does nothing.

Here are my settings

```
# $wgGroupPermissions['user']['wysiwyg'] = true; //Only registered users are allowed to use wysiwyg
# $wgGroupPermissions['*']['wysiwyg'] = true;    //Everyone is allowed to use wysiwyg
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['wysiwyg'] = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['wysiwyg'] = true;

$wgDefaultUserOptions['cke_show'] = 'WYSIWYG';    //Enable CKEditor
#$wgDefaultUserOptions['cke_show'] = 'richeditor';    //Enable CKEditor
$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_use_toggle'] = false;  //Editor can toggle CKEditor/WikiText
$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_start_disabled'] = false; //Important!!! else bug...
$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_toggle_remember_state'] = true; //working/bug?
$wgDefaultUserOptions['riched_use_popup'] = true;   //Deprecated
```

Comment: AFAIK, CkEditor is not part of a default MediaWiki installation but Wikia for instance is using it or a similar editor. I assume you're using [`Extension:WYSIWYG`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WYSIWYG)?

Answer (score 0):

The way `action=render` does it is by calling `$outputPage->setArticleBodyOnly( true )`; you might try to do that in some hook such as [BeforePageDisplay](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/BeforePageDisplay).